# Terminating a .net-core WebApp if there is a critical error

Tags: c#, .net-core, web-applications

In order to make deployment easier I want my application to self create pre-defined roles on the database.
If for some reason it is the first time running on the current database but it fails to create the roles, PE, there was a connection error, the application immediately terminates with an `Environment.Exit(-1);`.

Is this a bad practice? If yes, why? What are my alternatives?

EDIT for clarity: I'm logging every exception/error with log4net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you know why the application terminated, it could be fine.  If this is in Production, you also should get an alert if this happens.

At the very least, you should log the error.  For a DB connection, you can add logic to try to reconnect either for some time or forever depending on your requirements.  Depending on the error you get back from the database, you can either try again or not.

In my applications, I take an approach of forever attempts but make sure to log any errors I get back such as bad credentials or timeout.  It is also good to have a 3rd system to monitor for errors and alert you.

Comment: I'm logging it with log4net. I like your suggestion, I might replace it with the infinite retry. Thank you.

Comment: Just make sure to have a delay between retries so you don't accidently launch a DOS attach on your database.

Comment: I ended up using this. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is bad practice, however it depends on who uses this. Are you the only one or are people going to be disturbed by a force quit with no explanation?

Showing an alert/message with a little bit of explanations or an error code would be useful in a lot of cases. Log the error you get from the database if possible and if the users from your app know what to do with it you can also share it in the alert/message.

Comment: This error is exclusively for me when deploying this app on other servers for the first time.

Comment: In that case it is a personal preference and it highly depends on the type/use of the app. I like to know why it fails and if you have multiple termination points which one of those did this. However logging the issue also solves this.

Comment: I'm using log4net to achieve what you recommended. Thank you for your input.